# Will Environment.Exit(int) kill my application with treads running unmanaged code?

Tags: c#, environment, fail-fast

I have a windows service which runs unmanaged code (using `DllImport`) in different threads.

Sometimes, the unmanaged code 'hangs'. Think of `while (true) ;`. When that happens, I need to kill the entire process (which automatically starts another because it's a windows service).

Is `Environment.Exit(int)` sufficient? Or will I need e.g. `Environment.FailFast(string)`?

Edit: I am unable to 'test' this. The freezes happen randomly.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: [Environment.FailFast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=netframework-4.8) _"Use the Environment.FailFast method instead of the Exit method to terminate your application if the state of your application is damaged beyond repair, and executing your application's try/finally blocks and finalizers will corrupt program resources. "_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the official Microsoft documentation, [`Environment.Exit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.8):

> Terminates this process and returns an exit code to the operating
>   system.

More usefully, the documentation goes on to state:

- Exit always terminates an application
- **Exit terminates an application immediately, even if other threads are running**

It sounds like `Environment.Exit` is perfectly sufficient for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Environment.Exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.exit?view=netframework-4.8) will kill all the threads running in the current process, including the main thread (and the process itself).

[Environment.FailFast](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.failfast?view=netframework-4.8) will log an event into the Application Log and then kill the process and all of the threads in the current process.